# Exit Inner For Loop

Tags: vba, excel

I am using Excel VBA for this project. The goal of the project is to have a worksheet that shows a number of columns. Each column is headed with an item code (for a scoop) and the quantity of the scoop in inventory. This part is created and functional.

I then want the workbook to search through the list of open orders, get the item id needed to create the product on the open order, and put it in the column of items previously created.

The following code is what I have so far

```
 For j = 2 to 264
   For p =2 to 300
     'If the item on the order matches the item on the material required sheet, then the variables are set and it starts the inner loop
      If Sheets("OOR").Cells(j, 5).Value = Sheets("BOM").Cells(p, 1).Value then
          FgScoQty = Sheets("OOR").Cells(j, 10).Value
          ItemScoop = Sheets("BOM").Cells(p, 4).Value
          FgItem = Sheets("BOM").Cells(p, 1).Value 
          'If they match, it then looks on the sheet with the columns to put this information in the next blank row of the correct column

          For x = 1 to 258
              If ItemScoop = Sheets("Sheet5").Cells(1, x).Value Then
                  lastRow = Sheets("Sheets5").Cells(Rows.Count, x).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                  Sheets("Sheet5").Cells(lastRow, x).Value = fgItem
                  Sheets("Sheet5").Cells(lastRow, x).Offset(0, 1).Value = fgScoQty
              End If 
          Next x 
     End If 
   Next p
 Next j
```

This works the first time perfectly

After that I get an issue on the line

```
 If ItemScoop = Sheets("Sheet5").Cells(1, x).Value Then
```

I am not sure why. I believe I need to exit the inner loop (loop x) after the condition has been met. I've done a lot of searching on the net since this seemed like a fairly common problem, but I cannot find anything that works.

When I try `Exit For` it seems to remove me from all my loops.

I want it to fill in the cells with the variables, and then return to the beginning and look at the next j.

Comment: just before the `End If` put `Exit For`

Comment: Where did you put the `Exit For`, for it to exit all loops? That's not what `Exit For` does - it only exits the loop body it's written in.

Comment: FWIW You will get a performance boost if you replace the loops with `.Find`

Answer (score 0):

You need to exit the loop once you achieve what you want
So to force the beginning of the next loop ( **j** ), you need to use the `Exit for`

Try it:

```
 For j = 2 to 264
   For p =2 to 300
     'If the item on the order matches the item on the material required sheet, then the variables are set and it starts the inner loop
      If Sheets("OOR").Cells(j, 5).Value = Sheets("BOM").Cells(p, 1).Value then
          FgScoQty = Sheets("OOR").Cells(j, 10).Value
          ItemScoop = Sheets("BOM").Cells(p, 4).Value
          FgItem = Sheets("BOM").Cells(p, 1).Value 
          'If they match, it then looks on the sheet with the columns to put this information in the next blank row of the correct column

          For x = 1 to 258
              If ItemScoop = Sheets("Sheet5").Cells(1, x).Value Then
                  lastRow = Sheets("Sheets5").Cells(Rows.Count, x).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                  Sheets("Sheet5").Cells(lastRow, x).Value = fgItem
                  Sheets("Sheet5").Cells(lastRow, x).Offset(0, 1).Value = fgScoQty
              End If 
          Next x

          'HERE YOU ESCAPE THE LOOP
          Exit For

     Else
     End If 
   Next p
 Next j
```